# cakephp 4 login problem with chrome (webkit) based browsers

Tags: google-chrome, cakephp, chromium, cakephp-4.x

I am porting an application from cakephp 3.7 to cakephp 4.4 and ran into a weird problem.
I am using firefox, but for testing purposes I have chromium and vivaldi installed to test webkit browsers.

The login works well with firefox, but with the two browsers mentioned above, after trying to login the user/password is invalid. The address bar extends with the query string ?redirect=%2F. Both apps in a localhost testing environment in a subdirectory, and use plain http not https.

The cakephp 3.7 version of the app works well with the webkit browsers also.
The apps using the same db, and again: in firefox it works well.

What could be the reason? I do not know where to start after google-ing around for a half an hour.

Comment: That's a standard redirect string to send you back to the root of the site after login. `%2F` is ASCII for `/`; the redirect parameter is the URL to go to after logging in, but URL encoded. If you were trying to reach some other access-restricted resource on the site, you'd get a longer redirect string with that resource encoded in it.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error made by me. In the meanwhile I made a custom route for /login (later firefox was unable to login also) but the Authentication middleware still have the /user/login redirection.

/login and /user/login are different and the Athentication component does not allow it for security reason. Maybe it should consider such routes in the future.